# How to find the path directory on shinyapps.io for the published files

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

My shiny application retrieves a few `MP4` and `pdf` files from  `addResourcePath("pdf_folder","E:/shiny/Correct")`. My app works correctly on my machine. After publishing the app on `shinyapps.io`, what would be the path for my files? or How I should find the current path for my files? since it does not recognize my `MP4` and `pdf` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could sort it out using `setwd(paste0(getwd()))`. Also, adding `addResourcePath("pdf_folder",paste0(getwd()))` for the files.